# How to only get the audio of YouTube videos running?

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, youtube, video-streaming

I've come across a rather strange problem. What I'm trying to do right now is only obtain the **audio** of a YouTube video for a given link. I've tried a couple of things but it either didn't work or wasn't efficient.

Thus I've decided to ask more experienced iOS developers in here. Thanks in advance.

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize web;

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame{
        NSString* embedHTML = @"<html><head> <style type=\"text/css\">body {background-color: transparent;color: white;}</style></head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed></body></html>";
        NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

        UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
}

-(IBAction)play{

    [self embedYouTube:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iw1aT5c1Lus" frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just play the video with your media player, but dont give it a frame, this will play the audio, but not load the image

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have changed the frame of the web page and embedYoutube frame but it didn't work. I uploaded my code.

Thanks again

Comment: Still couldn't do it please could you help me ?